# Scraping html, keep getting errors I can't explain

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Scraping the price of a coin/token from Poocoin. This might sound unbelievable but I haven't been able to make this work.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token_poo = requests.get("https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x3d29aa78fb558f84112bbc48a84f371147a920c9")
soupb = BeautifulSoup(token_poo.content, 'html.parser')

#print price
price = soupb.find_all('div', class_='mb-1 d-flex flex-column lh-1')
pricebox = price.find('span', class_='text-success').get_text()
#print("Price: " + (pricebox).strip())
print(pricebox)
```

It works for bscScan when using find(id=) but bscScan prices are oftentimes useless.
Hopefully not too stoopid of a question,
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting? I tried the same thing manually using Javascript and it seemed to work.

Comment: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` is one. When I follow the suggestion it throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` I've read about these and moved the code around a little but haven't been able to fix it... Have you expanded on the idea yet?

Comment: running the code, price variable is an empty list. the first error u got probably looked at the list and suggested u use only 1 element from it, even thou its empty. So your find_all found nothing matching

Comment: that makes sense, yeah. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

I printed the request content with `token_poo.text` as well as `soupb.prettify()` and it turns out the element doesn't exist as it is asynchronously loaded by JavaScript. Requests can't handle dynamically generated elements by JavaScript. A suggestion is to use selenium together with PhantomJS to get the page source, then you can use BeautifulSoup for your parsing.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x3d29aa78fb558f84112bbc48a84f371147a920c9"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soupb = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#Then try the rest of the code
price = soupb.find_all('div', class_='mb-1 d-flex flex-column lh-1')
pricebox = price.find('span', class_='text-success').get_text()
#print("Price: " + (pricebox).strip())
print(pricebox)
```